# сколько действует аккаунт разработчика Google play?

Tags: android

сколько действует аккаунт разработчика  Google play? один год или больше?

Comment: Этот вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. он не относится к тематике StackOverflow

Comment: Вопрос неоднозначный. емнип 25$ в год, но у меня, например, год прошел, а никаких изменений не заметил.

Comment: @Sublihim вполне себе относится.

Comment: Я тоже купил год назад. И непонятно отключат или нет

Comment: Тут спрашивали как вывести деньги в другом вопросе. И никто не закрыл этот вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет срока действия. В [условиях соглашения](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) ([на русском](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ru/about/developer-distribution-agreement/archive.html)) четко прописано, что действие аккаунта прекращается только если Вы или Google прекратите его действие. С Вашей стороны:

> 10.2 Если Вы желаете расторгнуть Соглашение, Вы обязаны уведомить компанию Google за 30 (тридцать) дней в письменной форме (кроме
>   случаев, определенных в Разделе 14.1) и прекратить использование всех
>   соответствующих учетных данных Разработчика.
>
> 14.1 Компания Google может вносить изменения в Соглашение в любое время, при этом Разработчику будет отправлено сообщение по электронной почте с описанием внесенных изменений.

Со стороны Google:

> 10.3 Компания Google может в любое время расторгнуть Соглашение, если:
>
> (A) Вы нарушите какой-либо пункт Соглашения;
>
> (Б) компания Google будет вынуждена так поступить во исполнение
>   закона;
>
> (В) Вы утратите статус добросовестного Разработчика;
>
> (Г) компания Google примет решение о прекращении работы Магазина.